# How does tf.keras.metrics.TopKCategoricalAccuracy differ from Precision@k?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Coming from recommender systems, precision@k is a popular metric.

> precision@k = number of relevant predictions in top k / k

On the tensorflow docs for tf.keras.metrics.TopKCategoricalAccuracy it states

> Computes how often targets are in the top K predictions.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/TopKCategoricalAccuracy

Which seems to be exactly the same as precision@k. Am I missing something or are they equivalent and it just comes down to TF/recommender terminology?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TopKCategoricalAccuracy and Precison at k , these two metrics are different from each other. let us see one example.

For instance in the recommendation usecase , we predict 5 movies ["A", "B", "C","D","F"] for a user and the user viewed Movie 'A' and rejected the rest.

1. Then precision at 1 = 1/1= 1
2. Then precision at 5 = 1/5(among 5 movies user select only one)
3. Top1CategoricalAccuracy(K=1)= 1 or 100%(Because in the prediction list the First movie 'A' was seen by the user)
4. Top5CategoricalAccuracy(K=5)= 1 or 100%(the right answer appears in your top five guesses)

Comment: From what I know, precision in recommendation is often actually "min-precision", in that the recall is used when we do not have k true elements. This is done in order not to punish when there is actually no better solution. But you are right, if we don't do this, then it is not equivalent.

Comment: If user watched movie A and E, still `Top5CategoricalAccuracy = 1`?

Answer (score -1):

No. you are totally right.
They both are the same metric.